# SeekBar moves automatically when I click previous RadioButton?

Tags: android, seekbar

Each time when I click RadioButtons, my SeekBar moves automatically for one progress in right.

Of course this is not why I want. I don't have unique clicker or something, should I close RadioButton differently?

```
    public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {

     boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

        // Check which radio button was clicked
        switch(view.getId()) {
            case R.id.match1:
                if (checked)                 
                    tekma1 = 3;
                break;
            case R.id.matchx:
                if (checked)             
                    tekma1 = 1;
                break;
            case R.id.match2:
                if (checked)
                    tekma1 = 0;
                break;            
        }


    final SeekBar mplayerControl = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.edit_mplay);
    mplayerControl.incrementProgressBy(1);
    mplayerControl.setMax(5);

    mplayerControl.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {


        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar mplayerControl, int progress, boolean fromUser){

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Missing important players: " + progress, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

Comment: You have written this   mplayerControl.incrementProgressBy(1); inside onRadioButtonClicked function which is getting called each time you click on radio button. What is your use-case when do you want seekbar to progress??

Comment: when it is clicked by user

Comment: I put it outside first function. Works..Thank you for pointing out!